# seemore/hide post with markdown content

Tags: reactjs, markdown-it

My `reactjs` web app display feed post content look like **Facebook Workplace**. ​My `post` data API:

```
post = { plainText: "some text", markdownText: "some **text**" }
```

I use lib `mardown-it` to convert markdown string to HTML. Post need seemore/hide content (like facebook workplace). I'm stuck when get collapse content.

Example:

Full content: `"blah blah some (and very long text) **text** blah blah"`

Full content HTML: `<p>blah blah some (and very long text) <strong>text</strong>blah blah</p>`

Collapse content (cut from markdownText): `"blah blah some (and very long text) **tex"`

I got wrong collapse content HTML: `<p>blah blah some (and very long text) **tex</p>`

My expect: `<p>blah blah some (and very long text) <strong>tex</strong></p>`

How can I get exactly collapse HTML like facebook workplace post. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem with a recursive function which filter content.

- Load HTML content to dom element
- Create a new element and recursive function which filter content
- Apply some filtering logic like max allowed text size
- Clone text elements and append to a new element
- Also you can add 'load more' button at the end instead of '...'

Example:

```
var fullElement = document.createElement('div');
fullElement.innerHTML = '<p>blah blah some (and very long text) <strong>tex</strong> next text<strong>tex</strong></p>';
var shortElement = document.createElement('div');
var allowedSize = 40;
var currentSize = 0;
function applyNodes(element, parent){
  for (let item of element.childNodes) {
    if (item.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      var newParent = document.createElement(item.nodeName);
      parent.appendChild(newParent);
      applyNodes(item, newParent);
    } else {
      var diff = allowedSize - currentSize;
      var value = item.textContent;
      if (item.textContent.length >= diff) {
        value = value.substring(0, diff) + '...';
        parent.append(value);
        currentSize += value.length;
        return;
      } else {
        parent.append(value);
        currentSize += value.length;
      }
    }
  }
}
applyNodes(fullElement, shortElement);
console.log(shortElement.innerHTML);
```

Output:

```
<p>blah blah some (and very long text) <strong>tex</strong> ...</p>
```

Comment: Example will work if you paste code to console.